# Azure IoTHub python sdkv2 connection issue

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-sdk-python

I want to establish a stable connection between my Rpi4 device to IoTHub Owner (not IOTHub device) using IotHub sdkv2 in python.

in Azure IoTHub sdk1, the class ([IotHubMessaging](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/v1-deprecated/service/samples/iothub_messaging_sample.py)) from iothub_service_client was used to establish a connection between IoTHub Owner and the device which provide a stable connection.

```
from iothub_service_client import IoTHubMessaging, IoTHubMessage, IoTHubError
```

But in the newer IotHub sdkv2, this class not more available.

I tried [IoTHubRegistryManager](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/azure-iot-hub/samples/iothub_registry_manager_c2d_sample.py) from sdkv2 which is built over AMQP to establish the same connection, but the commutation is not stable and disconnected after 10 - 15 mins

```
registry_manager = IoTHubRegistryManager.from_connection_string(connection_str)
```

Is there any stable replacement for the IoTHubMessaging class in sdkv2 that can I use?

Answer (score 1):

To establish the stable connection, we need to pass the specific parameters to the connection string.

Check TestFromConnectionString python class to understand about passing the parameters.

Below block helps us to understand about passing the parameters to a connection string.

```
pytest.param(
                "HostName={hostname};DeviceId={device_id};SharedAccessKeyName={skn};SharedAccessKey={sk}".format(
                    hostname=fake_hostname,
                    device_id=fake_device_id,
                    skn=fake_shared_access_key_name,
                    sk=fake_shared_access_key,
                ),
                id="connection string with HostName, DeviceId, SharedAccessKeyName, and SharedAccessKey",
            ),
pytest.param(
                "HostName={hostname};SharedAccessKeyName={skn};SharedAccessKey={sk}".format(
                    hostname=fake_hostname,
                    skn=fake_shared_access_key_name,
                    sk=fake_shared_access_key,
                ),
                id="connection string without DeviceId"
            )
```

For better understanding, refer to the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/azure-iot-hub/tests/test_iothub_registry_manager.py)

Add required Imports for using the classes, modules in RegisterManager and try catch is the possible way for capturing the exceptions:

```
from azure.iot.hub import IoTHubRegistryManager

connection_str = os.getenv("IOTHUB_CONNECTION_STR")
device_id = os.getenv("IOTHUB_DEVICE_ID")

try:
    # Create Manager
    registry_manager = IoTHubRegistryManager.from_connection_string(connection_str)
    print("Conn String: {0}".format(connection_str))

    # Send Message 
    send_message = "Sending c2d message 1"
    registry_manager.send_c2d_message(device_id, send_message)

except Exception as ex:
    print("error {0}".format(ex))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("iothub_registry_c2d stopped")
```

Apart from all these connections we have a regular problem with the connections, and they usually depend on language which we are using.

To understand better refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-troubleshoot-error-404104-deviceconnectionclosedremotely) from Microsoft which gives us insight about connection problems

As we are using Python SDK to establish connections, below screenshot gives us the information about Reliability based on language. For more details on this refer [Manage connectivity and reliable messaging by using Azure IoT Hub device SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-reliability-features-in-sdks)

[Reliability for Python SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XmwJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

we also released an update to the sdk recently that helps address disconnect issues.

https://pypi.org/project/azure-iot-device/